# PDFBox - Extract rotated text

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pdf, pdfbox

I am currently trying to extract text from PDF files using PDFBox, but the problem is that these PDFs are rotated, so I need to find the rotation angle and rotate them accordingly.

**This is the code:**

```
    public void wawa(String pdfRoute) {
        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfRoute))) {
            for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PDPage page = document.getPage(i);
                
                PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
                
                stripper.setSortByPosition(true);
                stripper.setAddMoreFormatting(true);
                
                String text = stripper.getText(document);
                
                Matrix matrix = stripper.getTextMatrix();
                
                if (matrix != null) {
                    double rotationAngle = detectRotationAngle(matrix);
                    System.out.println("Page rotation angle: " + (i + 1) + ": " + rotationAngle + " grados");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Couldn't get text matrix for page " + (i + 1));
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public int detectRotationAngle(Matrix matrix) {
        int direction = -1;
        if (direction < 0) {
            float a = matrix.getScaleY();
            float b = matrix.getShearY();
            float c = matrix.getShearX();
            float d = matrix.getScaleX();
            // 12 0 left to right
            // 0 12
            if (a > 0 && Math.abs(b) < d && Math.abs(c) < a && d > 0) {
                direction = 0;
            }
            // -12 0 right to left (upside down)
            // 0 -12
            else if (a < 0 && Math.abs(b) < Math.abs(d) && Math.abs(c) < Math.abs(a) && d < 0) {
                direction = 180;
            }
            // 0 12 up
            // -12 0
            else if (Math.abs(a) < Math.abs(c) && b > 0 && c < 0 && Math.abs(d) < b) {
                direction = 90;
            }
            // 0 -12 down
            // 12 0
            else if (Math.abs(a) < c && b < 0 && c > 0 && Math.abs(d) < Math.abs(b)) {
                direction = 270;
            } else {
                direction = 0;
            }
        }
        return direction;
    }
```

i'm getting warnings saying

```
2024-03-12T10:32:39.497-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 81 (81) in font null
```

These warnings go from 0 to 90.

**This is the output**:

> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.491-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 0
> (0) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 1 (1) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 2 (2) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 3
> (3) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 4 (4) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 5 (5) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 6
> (6) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 7 (7) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for .notdef (8) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 9
> (9) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 10 (10) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 11 (11) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 12
> (12) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 13 (13) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 14 (14) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 15
> (15) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 16 (16) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 17 (17) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 18
> (18) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 19 (19) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 20 (20) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 21
> (21) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 22 (22) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 23 (23) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.492-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 24
> (24) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 25 (25) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 26 (26) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 27
> (27) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 28 (28) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 29 (29) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 30
> (30) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 31 (31) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 32 (32) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 33
> (33) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 34 (34) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 35 (35) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 36
> (36) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 37 (37) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 38 (38) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 39
> (39) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 40 (40) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 41 (41) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 42
> (42) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 43 (43) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 44 (44) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 45
> (45) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 46 (46) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.493-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 47 (47) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 48
> (48) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 49 (49) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 50 (50) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 51
> (51) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 52 (52) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 53 (53) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 54
> (54) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 55 (55) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 56 (56) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 57
> (57) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 58 (58) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 59 (59) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 60
> (60) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 61 (61) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 62 (62) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 63
> (63) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.494-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for .notdef (64) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 65
> (65) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 66 (66) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 67 (67) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 68
> (68) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 69 (69) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 70 (70) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 71
> (71) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 72 (72) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 73 (73) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.495-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 74
> (74) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.496-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 75 (75) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.496-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 76 (76) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.496-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 77
> (77) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.496-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 78 (78) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.497-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 79 (79) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.497-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 80
> (80) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.497-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 81 (81) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.501-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 82 (82) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.503-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 83
> (83) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.504-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 84 (84) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.504-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 85 (85) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.505-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 86
> (86) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.505-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 87 (87) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.505-03:00
> WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont
> : No Unicode mapping for 88 (88) in font null
> 2024-03-12T10:32:39.505-03:00  WARN 8234 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]
> o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No Unicode mapping for 89
> (89) in font null 2024-03-12T10:32:39.505-03:00  WARN 8234 ---
> [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDSimpleFont     : No
> Unicode mapping for 90 (90) in font null Couldn't get text matrix for
> page 1 Couldn't get text matrix for page 2 Couldn't get text matrix
> for page 3

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: The warnings indicate that your issue is _not_ the rotation but that the fonts used here do not supply the information required for regular text extraction. For more details, please share the PDF in question. Beware, though, usually this missing information cannot easily be reconstructed.